# Views Slideshow, show alternating content types

Tags: views

Does anyone have an idea how i might display a slideshow with alternating data (odd even style) of content type?

Currently the view is loading the fields, and i guess it could be one step closer to load the rendered node, but how can one alternate it, and limit it?

So like :
Slide 1: Article
Slide 2: blog
Slide 3: Article
Slide 4: blog
etc..

Comment: Bit of a mad idea that might work without having to mess with custom templates. Get the views_php module. Create a view and choose rendered entity/rendered content field for each type of alternating content you want and choose to exclude them (make sure they have view modes unique to that specific content type). Use a views php field to show one of the above fields based on whether its an odd or even from the available views data. Not adding as an answer as I have no idea if it would work!

Answer (score 0):

In broad strokes, you could use Views' [views_pre_render()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) hook to reorder the result of the View, eg...

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

   switch ($view->name) {

      case 'NAME_OF_YOUR_SLIDESHOW_VIEW':

        // to figure out what you have to work with, take out when done debugging
        drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($view->result, TRUE) . '</pre>');  

        // and here are the broad strokes... cycle through $view->result and
        // grab all the "rows" and re-order them by whatever business logic
        // you need, in this case even or them by content type instead of whatever
        // logic it is sorted in originally.  it you then set $view->result to this
        // new order, it will then be rendered by the Slideshow in that order

        break;

      // other Views might go here

   }

   // other code might go here, too...

}
```